# Is ther any Open source server monitoring tools available?

Tags: monitoring

Please let me know if there are any opensource server monitoring tool especially for AWS servers.(Other than Nagios).

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with Nagios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is listed open source server monitoring tool

```
1 - Nagois
2 - Zabbix
3 - Cacti
4 - OpenNMS
5 - Icinga
```

For more information go [Here](https://geekflare.com/best-open-source-monitoring-software/)